# Twitter Feed not pulling in with code?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

I'm wondering why the below code I'm trying to use to pull in a twitter feed of latest tweets, isn't working?

***CODE:***

```
<?
    $username = "readitforward";
    $limit = 5;
    $feed = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name='.$username.'&count='.$limit;
    $tweets = file_get_contents($feed);

        $tweets = str_replace("&", "&", $tweets);   
        $tweets = str_replace("<", "<", $tweets);
        $tweets = str_replace(">", ">", $tweets);
        $tweet = explode("<item>", $tweets);
    $tcount = count($tweet) - 1;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $tcount; $i++) {
    $endtweet = explode("</item>", $tweet[$i]);
    $title = explode("<title>", $endtweet[0]);
    $content = explode("</title>", $title[1]);
        $content[0] = str_replace("&#8211;", "&mdash;", $content[0]);

        $content[0] = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,68})[^\s<]*)/", '<a href="http://$2$3" target="_blank">$1$2$4</a>', $content[0]);
        $content[0] = str_replace("$username: ", "", $content[0]);
        $content[0] = preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/\\1\" target=\"_blank\">@\\1</a>", $content[0]);
        $content[0] = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href=\"http://search.twitter.com/search?q=\\1\" target=\"_blank\">#\\1</a>", $content[0]);
    $mytweets[] = $content[0];
}

while (list(, $v) = each($mytweets)) {
    $tweetout .= "<div>$v</div>\n";
}
?>
```

***OUTPUTTED ERROR:***

```
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /data/24/1/0/139/1815302/user/1967139/htdocs/RIF/wp-content/themes/crown_readitforward2012/sidebar.php on line 93

Warning: file_get_contents(http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=readitforward&count=5) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /data/24/1/0/139/1815302/user/1967139/htdocs/RIF/wp-content/themes/crown_readitforward2012/sidebar.php on line 93

Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in /data/24/1/0/139/1815302/user/1967139/htdocs/RIF/wp-content/themes/crown_readitforward2012/sidebar.php on line 114
```

**Line 93:**    `$tweets = file_get_contents($feed);`

**Line 114:** `while (list(, $v) = each($mytweets)) {`

*What did I do wrong here???*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

allow_url_fopen is turned off, so you have to fetch the remote file another way.

http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

you can use cURL instead or other php extensions.

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

for the second error check if(is_array($mytweets)) .. before doing the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Check out twitter API updates.

Change your `$feed` variable to:

```
$feed = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name='.$username.'&count='.$limit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Open `php.ini` and enable `allow_url_fopen`. This can not be done with `ini_set()`.

Alternatively, use a different method of requesting the URLs, such as cURL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the instructions; I'm needing to create a php.ini file thought. I've created the file in the root directory of the Wordpress install; but what exactly should I code in there to make this change? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `phpinfo()` should tell you where the current one is.

Comment: Thanks again, but what do I do with that snippet to locate an .ini file?

Comment: I found an ini file here: /data/24/1/0/139/1815302/user/1967139/cgi-bin/.php/php.coalesced.ini  (Does that mean going through the host?)

Comment: @cam77 You can make an enquiry with your host.